# How to use Filestream with embedded resource file?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I have a code that opens file using filestream as below:-

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("abc.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
```

I do not want to have it in any any directory rather I want it in embedded resource. I just copied the file in solution explorer and changed build action to embedded resource, now what should I do next to get it worked and achieve similar code behavior as above!
Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad, particularly because doing _exactly_ what you're asking is impossible. An embedded resource is, by definition, _not_ a file. But `FileStream` works only on files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140

Comment: Given that what you're asking for literally, is just not possible, you have two alternatives: treat the resource as a `Stream`, not `FileStream`; or copy the resource out to an actual file, and then use `FileStream` on that file. See marked duplicates for these two options.